# How to have multiple image paths in array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I need to display both .png's and .jpg's, but am unsure of how to display both.  The code below works:

```
NSArray *imagePaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"CarSeats"];
```

But this doesn't:

```
NSArray *imagePaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png, jpg" inDirectory:@"CarSeats"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the PNG and JPG paths separately and then combine the arrays:

```
NSArray *pngPaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png"
                                                       inDirectory:@"CarSeats"];
NSArray *jpgPaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg"
                                                       inDirectory:@"CarSeats"];
NSArray *imagePaths = [pngPaths arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:jpgPaths];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make two calls, (one each for jpg and another for png) and merge the arrays.

Use `- (NSArray *)arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)otherArray` to combine the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

pathsForResourcesOfType is expecting a string type and not an array of types, so you will need to grab the png images in one step, then the jpg images in another. Example:

```
NSArray *pngs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"catMemes"];
NSArray *jpgs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"catMemes"];
NSArray *imagePaths = [pngs arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:jpgs];
```